Unexpected EOF error from `aws s3api` call?
I have a bash script that downloads S3 objects into a TEMP_FILE and then uses jq to determine if that object has malformed JSON or not. This actually works pretty well:
#!/bin/bash

BUCKET_NAME="<REDACTED>" # assume this string is correct
COMMON_PREFIX="<REDACTED>" # assume this string is correct
AWS_PROFILE="<REDACTED>" # assume this string is correct
OUTPUT_FILE="./malformed_json_$(date +%Y%m%dT%H%M).txt"
TEMP_FILE="$(mktemp)"

# Fetch the list of objects and continuation token
args=(--bucket "$BUCKET_NAME" --prefix "$COMMON_PREFIX" --output json --profile "$AWS_PROFILE")
response=$(aws s3api list-objects-v2 "${args[@]}")
echo "Received responses for metadata objects!"

# Parse the response to get object keys
keys=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.Contents[] | select(.Key | endswith("metadata.json")) | .Key')

# Write object key to file if object is malformed
for key in ${keys}; do
  printf "Processing: %s\n" "$key"
  aws s3api get-object --bucket "$BUCKET_NAME" --key "$key" --profile "$AWS_PROFILE" "$TEMP_FILE" >/dev/null 2>&1
  if jq -e . "$TEMP_FILE" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    :
  else
    echo " --- INVALID JSON FOUND --- "
    echo "$key" >>"$OUTPUT_FILE"
  fi
done
echo "Finished processing metadata objects!"

rm "$TEMP_FILE"
echo "Cleaned up temporary file!"

...but the issue I'm having is that the script crashes once all keys are exhausted with the following errors:
/malformed_json.sh: line 32: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./malformed_json.sh: line 33: syntax error: unexpected end of file

This is fine since I get the answers I need (it properly identifies the malformed JSON), but I don't like the bug that causes a crash rather than exiting successfully.
When I comment out the aws s3api command, everything "works" fine (i.e., it doesn't do any processing since TEMP_FILE stays empty, but it does exit gracefully). I'm wondering why I'm getting this error...there isn't any obvious syntax error (at least when I check with shellcheck and tired eyes).
(I'd like to get better at writing these sort of scripts, so any advice is well-received!)

Update: When I run the script with the if ... fi block commented out, but leaving in the aws s3api get-object ..., things exit gracefully (no crash, I'm able to make the API calls fine). So, given that and that the script does't crash when the get-object call is omitted, it seems the issue only arises when both are left in!
Running the above with set -x doesn't give me back any additional info -- same errors as mentioned above.

what is line 32?  and 33?

Not your immediate problem, but for key in ${keys} is itself buggy. If you want to iterate over values, those values should be stored in an array, not a string. (You aren't showing us how you populate keys, so I can't show concrete replacement code).

To fix the immediate problem, though, we really need a [mre] -- code that produces the exact error you're asking about when run without any changes at all. An error message that talks about line 32, of course, can't be produced without at least 32 lines of code; so if you truly have a 17-line reproducer, your error message should contain a line number that's no greater than 17.

BTW: (1) if you haven't run your code through http://shellcheck.net/, I strongly recommend it. (2) The error message implies that your real code (including the parts you aren't showing us) is parsing data as code; that's a serious smell for security problems, so it's better to figure out the actual cause than to merely find a workaround.

...as another aside, make sure you send log messages to stderr, not stdout -- that both sets buffering behavior that's appropriate for error reporting, and makes sure that log messages don't get caught up in pipelines; it also makes your script comply with POSIX standards, which specify that stderr is for "diagnostic output"; things like status messages are diagnostic in nature.

(And avoid all-caps names for variables you define yourself -- POSIX reserves all-caps names for variables meaningful to OS-provided tools; the standard linked speaks to environment variables, but setting a shell variable overwrites any preexisting like-named environment variable so the conventions necessarily apply to both classes).

My fault, y'all -- updated my question to provide the full script!

I don't see any missing " that might cause that problem. Are you sure your actual script doesn't have any non-ASCII quotation marks in it? I'd recommend commenting out lines at the end of the script, one at a time and working backwards, until you eliminate the error. The supposed opening quote should then be on the last line you commented out.

Hmmm...checking to see if anything is outside of ASCII byte range with pcregrep --color='auto' -n '[^\x00-\x7F]' malformed_json.sh  returns nothing.

Since your pcregrep does not find something unusual, just a vague idea: Could the bash running the script somehow believe that it is interactive? In this case, the ! in the two echo commands could cause trouble. For a test, remove them. Aside from this, run your script with set -x and show us what you get.

Interesting... when I redirect the echo commands to stderr, everything seems to work!
